# Why would one $(document).ready(function() { prevent another from running?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand that I am SUPPOSED to be able to run and many $(document).ready(function() { as I like, but the fact is, on my page, I CAN NOT. While I appreciate people letting me know that I should be able to do that, I am really hoping that someone might be able to tell me why one of these functions is preventing the other from running.

I am running two separate $(document).ready(function() { on the same page. One is used to update a drop down meny when a search result is selected. The other is used to call a calendar function when a user clicks in the "date" text box. The date function works fine unless I call the name search function. If I do call the name search function, the Date function just doesn't run at all. I am a php hack, and really know almost nothing a javascript.

The two functions are included in different "js" pages. Here are the two functions:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="<?php echo MAIN_BASE_PATH?>/includes/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){
jquery_date('date');
});
</script>



function jquery_date(name){
$("input[name='"+name+"']").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'  });
}
```

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#student_search").autocomplete("autocomplete_student.php", {
           selectFirst: true
    });

     $("#student_search").result(function(event, data, formatted) {

        $("#student_menu_<?php echo $field_name;?>").val(data[1]);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I can only see one `$(document).ready()` usage in your code.

Comment: Even if you'd have two $(document().ready() that shouldn't be a problem, your problem lies somewhere else in the code.

Comment: @Angel  - yes I know that you should be able to call both, I am trying to figure out where the problem with the code lies, that is why I have included the code here. Any ideas what coding error would make twp $document.ready() functions work fine when they are on their own, but one of them stop working when they are together?

Comment: @DanielB I have anded the second $(document).ready(). Any ideas?

Comment: Is the 1st snippet also the first in your final document, then it's possible, that jQuery isn't loaded at the time you are adding your 1st document ready callback, because you are loading jQuery in your 2nd snippet.

Comment: @DanielB it's actually the datepicker that is not loading. I ran FireBug and it's telling me that datepicker isn't a function at all, whether I run the second or not. Seems weird, but that could be the problem. I will find datepicker and see why it is not being recognized. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check at which position you include jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily merge the two into one (after all your page is fully loaded at the time of the call).

The problem with multiple binds is if one of them fails with an error the next ones in chain won't be executed, is it possible for your code to generate such an error ?
(corrected previous post based on Alex comment, 10x added a +)

See Deli's post:
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: You can bind to document ready as much as you like in jQuery.

Comment: @mihaisimi - I guess it is possible that it is throwing an error. Any way to check? Sorry I only know php.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is that one of the the <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script> calls is in the HEADER and the other is in the body?